# PowerQuery - JSON web query - extra characters at the end of JSON input

Tags: json, powerquery

i lookup for this answer in many forums, but I cannot see what is wrong with my code. Can someone please help me?

This is the text of Conteudo:

```
{
    "search": {
        "Client" : ["xxxxxxxx"],
        "DateEmissionStart": "01/07/2021",
        "DateEmissionEnd": "31/07/2021",
        "Take": "1"
    }
}
```

[image: Error]

EDIT1:
This exactly code workout in the Postman.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151940/power-query-make-http-post-request-with-form-data

Comment: @AlexisOlson Since my recoard has a list inside, I get an error "Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Text" in the step "Uri.BuildQueryString". I even try using JSON.FromValue from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614882/power-query-expression-error-a-value-of-type-record-cannot-converted-into-typ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. If you pay attention to my response, the format is not JSON, it is HTML. In this particular API I need to request using a parameter **JSON: true**. So in my case the correct header is:

```
{
    "search": {
        "Client" : ["xxxxxxx"],
        "DateEmissionStart": "01/07/2021",
        "DateEmissionEnd": "31/07/2021",
        "Take": "1",
        "Json": true
    }
}
```

If this happends to you, check the response format in the Postman.